# chemmacros: Space in Compound name with \iupac

Tags: spacing, chemistry, chemmacros

In the following example there is no space before "chloride" as intended.
However, when i remove the oxidation number "(III)", the space is there as it should be.
Why is that and how can i force a space inside the \iupac command?
And btw, is it the correct way to just type "(III)" in that case?

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman,british]{babel}

%FONTS
\usepackage{mathptmx}   %Etwas Times New Roman Aehnliches
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%DIVERSES
\usepackage{graphicx}   %[draft]: Platzhalter für Bilder
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array, color, epstopdf, lipsum, pdfpages, textgreek, url}

%CHEMIE UND PHYSIK
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty = true, range-units = brackets, per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={all},greek=default}

\begin{document}
\section{Aim of the Experiment}
The aim of this experiment is the enantiospecific synthesis of the complex \iupac{(R,R)\-N,N'-bis(3,5-di-tert-Butyl|salicydene)-1,2-cyclo|hexane|diamino|manganese(III) chloride}, \ch{[Mn(salen)Cl]} or \emph{Jacobsens Catalyst}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess some `\@ifnextchar` breaks in the way, so spaces get ignored; you might try `\ ` (backslash space).

Comment: I don't understand why but it works, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is an erroneous definition of `\chemmacros_allow_hyphens:`. I'll fix it in the next version. Here is a temporary fix:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={all},greek=textgreek}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ChemCompatibilityTo{5.7}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \chemmacros_allow_hyphens:
  {
    \chemmacros_nobreak:
    \skip_horizontal:N \c_zero_skip
  }
\EndChemCompatibility
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\iupac{\cip{R,R}-\N,\N'-bis(3,5-di-\tert-Butyl|salicydene)-1,2-cyclo|hexane|%
  diamino|manganese(III) chloride}, \ch{[Mn(salen)Cl]} or \emph{Jacobsens
  Catalyst}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: it should be `\cip{R,R}-\N,\N'-bis(3,5-di-\tert-`… to follow iupac guidelines. Also setting `greek=default` doesn't really make sense as that leads to *italic* lowercase Greek letters!

Answer (score 1):

What probably happens is that `(...)` triggers some looking ahead, which ignores spaces when acting.

I don't know whether the syntax you're using is correct according to IUPAC norms; anyway, control space works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={all},greek=default}

\begin{document}

\section{Aim of the Experiment}
The aim of this experiment is the enantiospecific synthesis of the complex
\iupac{(R,R)\-N,N'-bis(3,5-di-tert-Butyl|salicydene)-1,2-cyclo|hexane|% <-- line break
diamino|manganese(III)\ chloride}, \ch{[Mn(salen)Cl]} or \emph{Jacobsens Catalyst}.

\end{document}
```

[image]